# Configurar XAMMP, apache y mysql para acceder a un proyecto desde red local

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

**Espero y tengan un excelente día** tengo un problema del cual quisiera consultar con esta comunidad.
Tengo un proyecto el cual funciona perfectamente en mi computador, el proyecto esta desarrollado con apache con el servidor XAMPP MYSQL el asunto es que al intentar abrir este proyecto conectado a un red wifi para acceder desde un celular o pc externo me arroja los siguientes mensajes sien las paginas a acceder conectan con la base de datos:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away
```

**Si** la base de datos **no** es llamada en la pagina entonces **la pagina carga sin problemas**.

Para conectarme modifique el archivo de configuración de apache "**httpd.conf**" en la linea:

"#Listen 12.34.56.78:80" > "#Listen **192.168.8.104**:80"(El cual es la direccion ip de mi ordenador conectado a la red)

Y cambie en mis archivos de conexion en php las lineas que tenia como:

`$dbHost = 'localhost';` las cambie a `$dbHost = '192.168.8.104';`

Adjunto todo el archivo de configuracion:

```
<?php
//DB details
$dbHost = '192.168.8.104';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'usuarios';

//Creamos conexión y seleccionamos mi base de datos usuarios
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```

Archivo PHP que no llama a la base de datos que si funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al cargar una pagina que use mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Vuelve a poner localhost como $dbHost

Comment: Ahh era eso, muchas gracias hermano si quieres comentarlo como respuesta para darte como respuesta correcta :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno puede que alguien mas llegue a tener este problema la solución en mi caso la dio el usuario José Carlos PHP.
Para solucionarlo es necesario dejar los archivos de conexión como localhost en el apartado del host del servidor.
De tal manera que la variable correctamente queda como:

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
```

Agradezco a ArtEze por su comentario

Comment: Es así. El motivo: los usuarios remotos acceden a tu aplicación web, pero NO a la base de datos. La aplicación es quién consulta a la base de datos, por eso si la BD está en el mismo servidor que la aplicación, entonces va localhost. Si la BD está en otro servidor, se debe crear una conexión segura desde la aplicación y en vez de `localhost`, entonces si va la IP.

Answer (score 1):

Eso significa que *MySQL* está desactivado.

Comprueba si alguna de estas dos carpetas, tiene permisos para el usuario *mysql* tiene permisos:

- **C:\xampp\mysql\data**
- **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data**

Estas carpetas hacen referencia a dónde se alojan las bases de datos... En caso de no existir, buscar la carpeta en donde se instaló el programa *XAMPP*.

Para cambiar los permisos de una carpeta cualquiera, hay que ir al explorador de archivos, luego click derecho en la carpeta, y en el menú, clickear en propiedades. Luego en la sección Seguridad, hay que mirar si tiene permisos para *mysql*... Si no tiene, hay que crear el usuario y darle los permisos.

Una vez hecho esto, hay que iniciar MySQL desde el panel XAMP o desde un comando, como el siguiente:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u root --password -h localhost
```

Comment: Aunque ya hay una solución simple, comento lo que pudo suceder: el servidor MySQL de su xampp escucha conexiones en localhost y no en la IP del host, por eso la conexion al SGBD le estaba fallando

Comment: @Francisco Es verdad, no lo tuve en cuenta.